LeScanner stop scanning after 1 minutes when run on foreground service
I want to make Ble Beacon Scanner run in the foreground while not opening the app UI. But when I run the service and exit from the app (but not kill the app) the scan just running for 1 minutes and stop scanning, but after I open the app again the scan continues. The service is not killed when the app is closed but just stop scanning.
class BleForegroundService: Service() {
    companion object {
        private const val CHANNEL_ID = "ble_scanner_channel"
        internal val TAG = BleForegroundService::class.java.simpleName
    }

    private lateinit var bluetoothManager: BluetoothManager
    private lateinit var bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
    private lateinit var bluetoothLeScanner: BluetoothLeScanner
    private val scanSettings = ScanSettings.Builder()
        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
        .build()
    private var scannedDevice: Int = 0

    private var scanFilter = arrayListOf<ScanFilter>()

    private val leScanCallback = BleScanCallback { result ->
        Log.d(TAG, "Result : $result")
        scannedDevice++
    }

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val notification = createNotification()
        startForeground(1, notification)

        Log.d(TAG, "Creating BleForegroundScanner")
        bluetoothManager = getSystemService(BluetoothManager::class.java)
        bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter
        bluetoothLeScanner = bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner

        val addressFilter = ScanFilter.Builder()
            .setDeviceAddress("E3:C4:8D:05:54:CF")
            .build()

        scanFilter.add(addressFilter)
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting Scanner")
        bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(scanFilter, scanSettings, leScanCallback)

        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Destroying BleForegroundScanner")
        bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(leScanCallback)
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    private fun createNotification(): Notification {
        val notificationChannelId = CHANNEL_ID

        // depending on the Android API that we're dealing with we will have
        // to use a specific method to create the notification
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                notificationChannelId,
                "Endless Service notifications channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            ).let {
                it.description = "Endless Service channel"
                it.enableLights(true)
                it.lightColor = Color.RED
                it.enableVibration(true)
                it.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400)
                it
            }
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).let { notificationIntent ->
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        }

        val builder: Notification.Builder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) Notification.Builder(
            this,
            notificationChannelId
        ) else Notification.Builder(this)

        return builder
            .setContentTitle("BLE Beacon Scanner")
            .setContentText("Scanning for BLE beacons")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker("Ticker text")
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH) // for under android 26 compatibility
            .build()
    }
}

And this inside MainActivity I wrote like this to start the service on Foreground
serviceIntent = Intent(this, BleForegroundService::class.java)
this.startForegroundService(serviceIntent)

I don't know what is the problem why the scan last just 1 minutes and stop scanning. But the service is not killed.

I get why the scan is stopped, my device is Xiaomi Redmi 9A. I'm pretty sure I already turned off the battery power saver in the setting. But Redmi has another app for battery saver that makes the my ble scanner stop after 1 minutes

To scan for BLE beacons on Android, your app needs these permissions:
Android 11 and below:
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions are required: This is because BLE scanning can be used to approximate a user's location.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>


Android 12 and above:
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, BLUETOOTH_SCAN permissions are required:
Location permissions are still needed if you are scanning for a BLE Beacon
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>


Scanning in the background (all Android versions):
ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission is essential: This allows your app to scan for beacons even when the app is not in the foreground.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>

You must grant "Allow all the time" instead of "Allow only while using the app" when Location permission is requested.
Note 1: You cannot request ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION simultaneously. You must first request ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, and then separately request ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION.
Note 2: Alternatively if you are scanning for a BLE device (which is not a beacon device) on Android 12 and above you just need to add the flag "neverForLocation" in the BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission. No other permissions are required.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"/>

